# Are those features supported?

Tags: coronasdk

Choosing corona as technology to build apps, I need to ask people who worked on it,

1. Can I use graphics from adobe flash swf file? to what level is it supported? would it be hardware accelerated vector graphics?
2. Is RTL language supported? like arabic for example?
3. Is there a rich UI framework? like mxml one in Flash Builder or Adobe Flex?
4. Is there native debugger? can I debug my app at native targets?
5. Is there native profiler for performance?
6. Are graphics filters supported? are they hardware accelerated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is a 3rd party software kit that allows you to convert flash animations over into corona. It's called Spriteloq: http://lanica.co/products/animo/spriteloq/ (keep in mind it's no longer a Corona offical product after the Lanica buy out).
2. I don't think it is.  Check the Corona Enterprise edition to see if it is.
3. There isn't much UI to it.  You just write some code, and see it on the simulator. Very fast and easy.
4. When you build your project in corona, you can build for iOS Phone Simulator, or run it via the Android Simulator. It takes around 15-20 seconds to build and run on a native simulator.  Honestly you don't need a native simulator though because Corona's is realtime and works very well.
5. I don't believe so, but it might be available in Corona enterprise.
6. With the new Graphics 2.0 engine, YES they are! Yes they are hardware accelerated.

Comment: Thanks, but point 3 is not clear, is there UI framework? grids, table, scroller, layouts, .. etc ?

Comment: Oh yes there is UI widgets built into corona.  It's called the widget library and you can implement UI easily into your app.  I thought you were asking if Corona had a GUI :D

Comment: Thanks Ninja for your answer!

Comment: Link is broken, dang.

This website says it's now called Animo, but that has a broken link too! http://www.loqheart.com/spriteloq/download.html